# Getting Exception while inserting data in Redshift DB

Tags: spring-data-jpa, amazon-redshift

while fetching data from database It is working fine when trying to insert data in Redshift database getting exception
MY POJO class : **Quote.java**

```
@Entity
public class Quote {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
@Column(name="user_name")
private String username;
private String quote;
}
```

Getting Exception :

```
com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist;
```

We cannto create sequence in Redshift but we can create sequence in postgresql
and when I am connect with redshift + spring-data-jpa then it is using postgresql db

`hbm2ddl.auto = update`

I have tried with identity also

Comment: Try to annotate your id with `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.

Comment: Hi Khan thanks for reply but I have used Identity also that I mentioned in my  question

Comment: @AbdullahKhan When I used `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` then getting exception is : `Hibernate: insert into Quotes (quote, user_name) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select currval('Quotes_id_seq')
2017-11-03 11:24:55.465  WARN 4976 --- [io-8300-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 500310, SQLState: 42P01
2017-11-03 11:24:55.465 ERROR 4976 --- [io-8300-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: relation "quotes_id_seq" does not exist;`

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Has anyone overcome this issue?

Comment: Has anyone solved this issue yet?

Answer (score 0):

I did GenerationType.TABLE and created table called sequence to overcome this.

CREATE TABLE sequence(seq_count bigint, seq_name varchar(65535));

But it seems to be very slow.